# SwiftTransport Exception : Expected response code 220 but got code "421"

Tags: email, symfony, smtp, swiftmailer

I am using `FOSUserBundle` with `Symfony2` , a few days ago the sign up processes works fine, then suddenly I get the folowing error when signing up  :

```
Expected response code 220 but got code "421", with message "421 Cannot connect to SMTP server x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x), connect error 10061
 500 Internal Server Error - Swift_TransportException
"
```

with :

```
x.x.x.x stands for smtp IP adress
```

It's related to smtp. 
Any idea  how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Check your smtp configuration, that's all the help we can provide! (421 means: `Service not available, closing transmission channel` so your SMTP server is probably down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @cheesemacfly said it was a problem of my `smtp` server. it was down.

I waited for a while reattempted an it worked fine.